# How to convert a SQLContext Dataframe to RDD of vectors in Python?

Tags: statistics, apache-spark

I have a SQLContext data frame derived from pandas data frame consisting of several numerical columns. I want to perform **multivariate statistical analysis** using the **pyspark.mllib.stats** package. The statistics function expects a RDD of vectors. I could not convert this data frame into RDD of vectors. Is there a way to convert the data frame?

**Code:**

```
 rdd = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(df_new)
 summary = Statistics.colStats(rdd)
```

I am getting df_new from

```
 df_new = df.applymap(lambda s: dic.get(s) if s in dic else s) #df is a pandas dataframe
```

I am getting a PY4JJava error at the summary line. The issue is with the format of rdd.

Comment: Which version of Spark are you using, and did the answer solve your problem? Please accept it if so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Dataframe Python API exposes the RDD of a Dataframe by calling the following :

```
df.rdd # you can save it, perform transformations of course, etc.
```

df.rdd returns the content as an pyspark.RDD of Row.

You can then map on that RDD of Row transforming every Row into a `numpy` vector. I can't be more specific about the transformation since I don't know what your vector represents with the information given.

Note 1: `df`is the variable define our Dataframe.

Note 2: this function is available since Spark 1.3